# Compose functions using generators

Tags: javascript, iterator, generator, currying, function-composition

I am trying to make composition using generators.

```
function A(x){return 1+x}
function B(y){return 2*y}
let val=tryCompose([A,B](1);     //output should be : A(B(1))
```

How should the generator function should look like

Comment: Why using generators? You don't have iterables here. Composing `A` and `B` with a generator will be an overkill, since you get a generator that `yield`s a single value. So, you can take any `compose` implementation and replace `return` with `yield` to that effect.

Comment: The signature of `tryCompose` is unclear because you have a typo in the call.

Comment: @GuerricP I'd assume it's `tryCompose(Function[]): Function` (if I use some TS). Takes an array of functions and returns a new function that composes them together. So the correct call would be `tryCompose([A, B])(1)`

Comment: does `A`, `B` function return generator?

Comment: @Nur not in the example by OP. Which is why I'm confused what the point is.

Comment: I think the example needs to be modified to read `tryCompose([A,B])(1)` (to be syntactically correct), with the intent being that `tryCompose` would return a function, which would then be called with the argument `1`.  Also it is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to presume the solution should make use of generators.

Answer (score 2):

The implementation of `tryCompose` could be this:

```js
function A(x) {
  return 1 + x;
}

function B(y) {
  return 2 * y;
}

function tryCompose(fns) {
  return fns.reduce((f, g) => (...args) => f(g(...args)));
}

const val = tryCompose([A, B])(1);

console.log(val);
```

Not sure why you need generators there.

Answer (score 2):

Using a generator for this task is not needed. You would end up with a generator that `yield`s a single result and single result only.

If you *really* need that, then I suggest to write a very simple generator wrapper that returns a single value:

```
function* single(value) {
  yield value;
}
```

And then take *any* implementation of functional composition and wrap it in the generator. Using [`compose` from Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#compose):

```js
function* single(value) {
  yield value;
}

//implementation
const tryCompose = fns => v =>
  single(compose(...fns)(v));

//usage
function A(x){return 1+x}
function B(y){return 2*y}

let val = tryCompose([A, B])(1);

const {value, done} = val.next();

console.log(value); // A(B(1)) = 1 + (2 * (1)) = 3
console.log(done);  // false

console.log(val.next()) // { done: true }
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const { compose } = R; </script>
```

Any implementation of `compose` will work here, even from other libraries. Even a simple custom one from:

```
const compose = (f, g) => x =>
    f(g(x));
```

```js
const compose = (f, g) => x =>
    f(g(x));

function* single(value) {
  yield value;
}

//implementation
const tryCompose = fns => v =>
  single(compose(...fns)(v));

//usage
function A(x){return 1+x}
function B(y){return 2*y}

let val = tryCompose([A, B])(1);

const {value, done} = val.next();

console.log(value); // A(B(1)) = 1 + (2 * (1)) = 3
console.log(done);  // false

console.log(val.next()) // { done: true }
```

to a variadic implementation like [what Guerric P demonstrated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68260054) (I modified it to keep the generic `compose` signature):

```
const compose = (...fns) =>
  fns.reduce((f, g) => (...args) => f(g(...args)));
```

```js
const compose = (...fns) =>
  fns.reduce((f, g) => (...args) => f(g(...args)));

function* single(value) {
  yield value;
}

//implementation
const tryCompose = fns => v =>
  single(compose(...fns)(v));

//usage
function A(x){return 1+x}
function B(y){return 2*y}

let val = tryCompose([A, B])(1);

const {value, done} = val.next();

console.log(value); // A(B(1)) = 1 + (2 * (1)) = 3
console.log(done);  // false

console.log(val.next()) // { done: true }
```

---

Since you have access to a `compose` anyway, you can refactor `tryCompose` to employ it in order to peel off part of the abstraction:

```
const tryCompose = fns => 
  compose(single, compose(...fns));
```

```js
function* single(value) {
  yield value;
}

// implementation
const tryCompose = fns => 
  compose(single, compose(...fns));

// usage
function A(x){return 1+x}
function B(y){return 2*y}

let val = tryCompose([A, B])(1);

const {value, done} = val.next();

console.log(value); // A(B(1)) = 1 + (2 * (1)) = 3
console.log(done);  // false

console.log(val.next()) // { done: true }
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const { compose } = R; </script>
```